# How to check if mod_wsgi is installed on a shared Apache server?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am looking into deploying a Django project on a shared server running Apache. This is my first time doing this. I have a shared folder on the server for my work and I have been added to the sudo group so I can install new software.

How do I check via Terminal command line if mod_wsgi is already installed? and preferably what version it is?

I can ssh onto the server, the version of Apache is

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 12 2013 13:37:10
$
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Just for future reference, after I ran the command `$ dpkg -s libapache2-mod-wsgi` provided by Dirk Eschler it showed me that it was not installed. It returned

```
Package `libapache2-mod-wsgi' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To check if it is installed:

```
$ dpkg -s libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

In case it is installed, you might check if it's loaded by Apache:

```
$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Answer (score 12):

Though you are on Ubuntu.

This might help someone else on CentOS, Fedora or Red Hat

```
rpm -q mod_wsgi
```

Comment: this result `mod_wsgi-3.4-12.amzn2.0.2.x86_64` in my amazon ec2 linux 2 instance. But browser shows 403 forbidden error

Answer (score 7):

Since you're on Ubuntu, which is Debian-based, you can look in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.

Comment: Thanks man. great tip. At least I now know where it should appear when I have it installed.

Comment: if ```mods-enabled``` exists, does this means mod_wsgi is installed? or the directory exists nevertheless?

Answer (score 1):

if you working with python in Red Hat
search this for mod_wsgi installed or not `yum search python3-mod_wsgi`

or search this for module is loaded or not `rpm -q python3-mod_wsgi`

[Read More about python](https://codewithronny.com/a-journey-into-the-world-of-python/)